# Is there an English word for the Japanese オブジェ?

Tags: single-word-requests

The Japanese word [オブジェ](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) means something like “avant-garde sculpture”, it does not apply to things like classical sculptures or 18th century busts. Most modern art sculptures are called オブジェ by Japanese people. I am not totally sure オブジェ is always art, as a decorative interior dead tree with no further processing can also be an オブジェ.

I can't find an equivalent word in English, is there any?

[Google Images](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) might give you a better idea of what it is used for.
Strangely, the word actually comes from the French “objet”.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/objet_d'art ?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR +1 I think you are very close.

Comment: What is the English transcription of the Japanese? (that might be a reasonable loan word)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: please add as a formal answer. I think that's the closest in English.

Comment: *Objet d'art* essentially just means work of art, though; it's not specific to sculpture in any way. Just based on the pictures in the linked Google image search, I'd be inclined to say *abstract sculpture*.

Comment: ShreevatsaR, @onomatomaniak, please add answers so that I can upvote them, and potentially select one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

<sub>*(Posting comment as answer on request.)*</sub>

The term ***objet d'art*** is sometimes used to describe works of art, and is used especially for modern sculptures and other "objects", as you want. It comes from French, and since the Japanese word you're asking about *also* comes from the French word *objet*, this may be appropriate.

See [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/objet_d%27art), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objet%20d%27art) ("The house is decorated with *objets d'art* from around the world"), [About.com's Art History Glossary](http://arthistory.about.com/od/glossary/g/o_objetdart.htm), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/objet+d%27art), or, especially, the Google Image Searches for [オブジェ](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) versus [*objet d'art*](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=objet+d%27art).

Comment: Pretty close! One thing troubles me: Google Images is not an absolute reference, but for オブジェ mostly modern art shows up, whereas for objet d'art mostly antique shows up.

Comment: @Nicolas: what is the transcription of that Japanese word into English letters? Does the Japanese term necessarily exclude non-modern art objects?

Comment: @Nicolas: maybe there is no word/phrase in English that captures exactly the Japanese idea, but objet d'art certainly includes it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is too specific, but [installation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_art) may be the equivalent English language word.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the French word *objet*.  (In English, that would have a slight mocking tone, which I regard as a plus.)

Comment: +1 Indeed, オブジェ is often a bit mocking. For instance, if I put an out-of-its-usual-context, bizarre tool at the middle of my desk, my colleagues would call it オブジェ as a joke.

Comment: Well, there you are.  Google pronounces オブジェ as "obajet"; if that's close, maybe the Japanese borrowed the word, sneering connotation and all, from English.

Answer (score 2):

If asked for a term to describe the results in the linked Google image search, I'd be inclined to say ***abstract sculpture***.

*Installations* refer to a variety of art exhibits that are installed in a gallery space or elsewhere; they aren't specific to sculpture.

Similarly, *objet d'art* essentially just means *work of art*; an elaborately made book, spoon or car could be an objet d'art but would not, I think, fall under the category OP is trying to describe.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of that [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) page is translated by Google Translate as:

> **Object** ( French : Objet) are things, objects, such as the meaning of being, in the English language falls object.

*Object* is a good word for something such as a sculpture or anything else inanimate, but would also include sculptures of people and (normally) animate objects.

I can't think of a work for sculptures that specifically excludes people and animate objects.

Edit: The [Google Images](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) link in the question shows plenty of sculptures of people and living things, so I would use the word *sculpture*.

Comment: They are indeed objects. Now I was just wondering if someone knew a more specific word.

Comment: Well spot! Indeed, representation of humans in modern art is also オブジェ, I updated my question.

Comment: Object is a bit too general. It can refer to any physical manifestation, artistic or otherwise.